# Difference in Double & double

Tags: c#, .net

I am confuse in term of lower-case double and upper-case Double.
what is the difference between double/Double... ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace test
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Double a = 100;
            double b = 200;

            Console.Write("{0},{1}",a,b);
        }

    }
}
```

Both do same work,so why looking different i.e, Double and double...?

Comment: `Double` i.e. `System.Double` is just a synonym of `double`

Comment: [Relevant docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

Comment: Other way round because double is C# language while System.Double is the structure

Comment: you mean either i use double or Double. They always do same work...?

Comment: @MuhammedNaqi Yes, they are equivalent. However, it is a good practice to use `double` as type, and `Double` if you refer to its static members.

Comment: AFAIK, `(Double)-1` will not compile, while `(double)-1` will.

Comment: @PetSerAl, that's wrong. You can using `system.double` like `(System.Double)(-1);`

Comment: @Rahul But you can not using it like `(System.Double)-1` because it interpreted as subtraction while `(double)-1` interpreted as cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double is `System.Double` while double is the C# double data type. They are the same, that means the C# double type maps to System.Double

Relevant documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Comment: It's C# and not C##. BTW, double is just an alias for system.double

Answer (score 0):

These are reserved 'keywords' and just maps to the other type (double maps to Double)
like said, it is an alias